# Modify Vega tooltip in spec to display specific fields

Tags: vega

I have a Vega spec and need to modify the tooltip:
[Vega Chart Editor - Donut Chart](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6SgBY6AK1jcAdpAA04KAHdGAExbYwARgBMABkURIKRtXxa9hpZHSs83WIwBeyLZABmzBSBtPqMugANrBaANpKEKAQMVCBqG44kLDIQcjweMhqPrHGFMGsiVA5uZCy4ZG5wFDIVDJ4oUnoAE7wWPBBjPAA1gCEClCshGrome4jeKyokGAAvka5UTV1DePsQR1dfQOQQxNFkADkhzOzlRAAupVnl4o2E5g4EbHRpfEHeOjrbguxkPlBQqNMDPRZgaqQADC3FY9Us8igAGVPpNgZAAPKEZByOa-KpQaGwvBaACsCMgyNGrDRACVkNIglRsrjzjEIYS4ThtAAOcmU1HuACSMgAtIRmtxqM16aE5qyLnjjHhmugZLAPNxmtMnqyorqYpA8ABPLHuQiMH764xeVLZJIc4mK0pSmGEdhG8IUlHUyBXMFyxZ+mI3MAK3zGBDBekVF6syDvdzwbhBTUlP7G01JTVqRiBIJpg0qmTUIoQ-hoA7wUY0TVGgyna5KMM2DDNbrA0F6xbx9AJdyt7oFpUmg4teBDqC5zIqjKMKhaZWFJ2eCXa8FQB7uT7fU7L7FJtSl-WQbHTrSvf2eRhBfM4MtVtKJ5Op8k2oJ2pHe2XzK1QAAe55QP4ebuKoGiIGApBgLou6-pAHp3kBZggUkpjmHgkHQbB-pKtwyZ4IwhDnskyHBOMVLTCGiw-peezVuecGwJ8zR4AAgsWj6IVetruExLRsRxbgsjhNQyGo7HUJx67ce+7jYuJgnYThkCEOgCmSUUYQQgChRaPodD6NocxhiJZT2MgzQ0mpjA+lxwFkUkYEsJhJJKZeSbNDIFlWTmtnSTpRT6MJym5l5lnWX5ZakbeYCiCSwWXtwqnwMwCEgtpBRFNoBnGU6fxeDe4T3lGT4ps0Oxvh+XpUt+QbUXluDcFQ5V3lRwaNpcIBnEAA)

[image: How to remove 'startAngle' and 'endAngle'?]

How to remove 'startAngle' and 'endAngle' from this tooltip?

Also I can add only one field:

```
 "tooltip": { "field": "Status"}
```

or

```
"tooltip": [{ "field": "Status"}]
```

But how I can add 2 fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the link for [vega editor-donut chart](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6SgBY6AK1jcAdpAA04KAHdGAExbYwARgBMABkURIKRtXxa9hpZHSs83WIwBeyLZABmzBSBtPqMugANrBaANpKEKAQMVCBqG44kLDIQcjweMhqPrHGFMGsiVA5uZCy4ZG5wFDIVDJ4oUnoAE7wWPBBjPAA1gCEClCshGrome4jeKyokGAAvka5UTV1DePsQR1dfQOQQxNFkADkhzOzlRAAupVnl4o2E5g4EbHRpfEHeOjrbguxkPlBQqNMDPRZgaqQADC3FY9Us8igAGVPpNgZAAPKEZByOa-KpQaGwvBaACsCMgyNGrDRACVkNIglRsrjzjEIYS4ThtAAOcmU1HuACSMgAtIRmtxqM16aE5qyLnjjHhmugZLAPNxmtMnqyorqYpA8ABPLHuQiMH764xeVLZJIc4mK0pSmGEdhG8IUlHUyBXMFyxZ+mI3MAK3zGBDBekVF6syDvdzwbhBTUlP7G01JTVqRiBIJpg0qmTUIoQ-hoA7wUY0TVGgyna5KMM2DDNbrA0F6xbx9AJdyt7oFpUmg4teBDqC5zIqjKMKhaZWFJ2eCXa8FQB7uT7fU7L7FJtSl-WQbHTrSvf2eRhBfM4MtVtKJ5Op8k2oJ2pHe2XzK1QAAe55QP4ebuKoGiIGApBgLou6-pAHp3kBZggUkpjmHgkHQbB-pKtwyZ4IwhDnskyHBO4wCHAReBpIcOCHAAKswNHyIcSZErRYATFMdAOgihywF+HFcagdD8tSsyQCGiw-peezVuecECS0eAAILFo+iFXra7hKc0qnqW4LI4TUMhqGp1AaeuWnvu42JmQZ2E4ZAhDoPZFlFGEEIAoUWj6HQ+jaHMYbGWU9jIM0NKuYwPqacBZFJGBLCYSSjmXkmzQyOFkU5jFVneUU+hGU5uaZRFUW5WWpG3mAogkkVl7cC58DMAhIJeQURTaP5QVOn8Xg3uE95Rk+KbNDsb4fl6VLfkG0m9bg3BUGNd5ScGjaXCAZxAA) with tooltip showing only count and status.

Vega `tooltip` property is limited to show only Title and data properties as `key: value`. The above shared link also shows `Title` but feel free to remove `title` key if not needed.

```
"tooltip": {"signal": "{'title': 'Title','count': datum.Count, 'status': datum.Status}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set `tooltip` to a `signal` describing an object mapping key to value:

```
"tooltip": {"signal": "{\"Count\": datum.Count, \"Status\": datum.Status}" }
```

For a full spec, see the Vega output of any Vega-Lite examples such as [this one](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/point_2d).

Comment: I saw it in the docs. Even tried, but didn't understand how can I use it in this particular situation with donut chart.

Comment: Ok. I just edited the code in the answer to make it work with your case.

Comment: Did you share it? It looks exactly the same like it was before.

Comment: I already updated -- you look at the signal part  now it is `{\"Count\": datum.count, \"Status\": datum.Status}`

Comment: it should be datum.Count instead of datum.count. That's why I had 'undefined', but didn't understand why. Now I got it. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for typo. Updated the answer.